# Ruby on Rails Internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

Hey, I try to make my config/locals organized in directories like the app directory. I can not get this to work... Here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html says you have to activate this manually under config like this

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

but when I try to use my constant in a view a get an error (missing/nil). Can someone write an example step by step? 10thx!

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve and what kind of error you get?

Comment: I would like to separate language constants (config/locals/en.yml) into separated files (config/locals/contollers/{controller}/en.yml, config/locals/models/{model}/en.yml, ...). I don't know how to do this (step by step).

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. I found out I did everything right :).

You have to add this

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

to the config/locales/environment.rb and then you can use whatever directory structure you want.

Comment: I was having the same problem (translation files in subdirectories were not getting picked up). In Rails 3 the config/application.rb file has this line, which you're supposed to just uncomment, but it wasn't working: `config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]` Not only do you need to add the '**', but you need to change 'my' to 'config', and then it will work: `config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]`